# Problem loading images into UITableView cell with SDWebImage

Tags: ios4, uitableview

I'm using SDWebImage to load images into my table cells - however the images aren't appearing until I've selected the row, when I see the image appear just as the table is being animated off the screen.  When I click back from my navigation controller the image is there.

Is this likely to be just a speed issue with the web or am I missing something?  This is being run on the simulator only at the moment if that makes a difference

Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell...

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

// Here we use the new provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mydomain.com/uploads/news1.png"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row];

return cell;
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Possibly may have fixed it - placeholder image filename was a typo and it seems to be working now.  I'll mark it as answered when I can if it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed, it was the placeholder image not being correct.  Sorry for wasting people's time...

Comment: Can you show the code or explain more you solved it? I have the same problem

Comment: Sorry, this was a project I did at my old employer - I no longer have the code and I've not touched ObjC since... from what I wrote here I think it's the 3rd line from the end where I had the name of the image or the path I was using incorrect.